# Gettting "The token is invalid" with error code 11502 in recurring payment paypal

Tags: java, paypal

I am using paypal subscription button and recurring payment.

I followed steps from paypal site to create recurring payment process.

I created subscription button and in my code I call `SetExpressCheckout` and get a token which works very fine. But when I call `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileAPI` and pass the token which I get from `setExpressCheckout` api, it is getting failed.

It is saying The token is invalid and getting error code `11502`.

here is the response message I am getting

```
TIMESTAMP=2012%2d10%2d17T13%3a22%3a12Z&CORRELATIONID=b64d1f16700ba&ACK=Failure&VERSION=57%2e0&BUILD=3926908&L_ERRORCODE0=11502&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20Token&L_LONGMESSAGE0=The%20token%20is%20invalid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

I tried with both soap api as well ad NVP api but getting same error.

here is my SetExpressCheckout Api call code

```
 encoder.add("RETURNURL", returnURL);
            encoder.add("CANCELURL", cancelURL);
            encoder.add("AMT", amount);
            encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION", paymentType);
            encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE", currencyCode);
            encoder.add("DESC", "Monthly Subscription");
            encoder.add("BILLINGTYPE","RecurringPayments");
```

and CreateRecrringPayment api call code

```
 encoder.add("METHOD", "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile");
        encoder.add("TOKEN", getToken);
        encoder.add("AMT", "25.00");
        encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE", "USD");
        encoder.add("PROFILESTARTDATE", "2012-10-17 12:00:00");
        encoder.add("BILLINGPERIOD", "Day");
        encoder.add("BILLINGFREQUENCY", "1");
        encoder.add("VERSION", "51.0");
        encoder.add("PROFILEREFERENCE", "795");
        encoder.add("MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS", "1");
        encoder.add("DESC", "USBSwiper Monthly Subscription");
        encoder.add("AUTOBILLAMT", "AddToNextBilling");
        encoder.add("LOCALECODE", "US");
        encoder.add("BUTTONSOURCE", "test product");
```

Please suggest something and if possible share some working code in java soap or nvp api.

Thanks in advance`enter code here`

Comment: Did you include L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments in your SetExpressCheckout API call?

Comment: Yes i added  BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments, also i posted my some of code above please review it and suggest solution.

Comment: You used BILLINGTYPE -- it should be L_BILLINGTYPE0. Can you modify and try again?

Comment: Robert i tried L_BILLINGTYPE0 this also but the issue is still not resolved